# Does the word "combats" refer to clothes as a whole or just the trousers of the particular kind?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences, american-english, british-english

I'd like to use this word correctly but the two dictionaries are saying two different things.

According to [**Cambridge Dictionary**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/combat-trousers), combats (in British English) means

> **combat trousers/pants**. Another word from British English would be
>   **cargo pants**.

However, [**Macmillan Dictionary**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/combats) offers a different meaning. According to them, combats are

> clothes with a military style that are worn by ordinary people.

I know that the Macmillan D. focuses on American English therefore I want to ask the natives which ways they've come across while using this word.

I focus more on British English so I'd like to know whether people from the UK would understand me if I said combats referring to the meaning of Macmillan Dictionary.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: If those dictionary quotes are from their online dictionaries, then you should include the hyperlink in your post.

Comment: It may well be dependent on context. *combats* can be short for *combat trousers* or for *combat fatigues*, as a British-English speaker I would not expect it to relate to any other kind of 'military style' clothing worn by civilians. For example, a Great Coat might be military'style or even military surplus, but you wouldn't call it 'combats'.

Comment: Also... Your MacMillan quote seems to be from the MacMillan *Open Dictionary* rather than their Main Dictionary. It is crowd sourced and they say only about half of everything published there makes it into their lexicographer compiled dictionary.

Comment: Collins English Dictionary says the word *combat* can be used as a modifier like *combat jacket* and that's the same usage that native speakers I know use in the US.  I suppose it would be understandable if someone said something like *I see you're wearing your combats today* with an implied reference to whatever battle dress uniform items I had on, so if I was wearing trousers and a matching shirt and cap all in military camo it would understandably refer to all of those without needing to actually name each item separately.  Also common would be *hunting gear* for these kinds of clothes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British English, with no further qualification, if almost certainly means combat (style) *trousers*. You normally get some hints of context anyway. Examples:

- "The suspect was wearing combats and a leather jacket."
- "Combats £20" (implying a single item).

If someone was dressed all over in military garb, you could describe them as wearing "full combats" or "fatigues", the latter implying actual army surplus rather than a high-street imitation.

Note that *cargo pants* is only acceptable in British English to the limited extent it's been adopted as a whole phrase from American use. *Pants* doesn't mean *trousers* (it means underwear) in most British English, though the *trousers* meaning had some currency in parts of the north of England and in some set phrases (*yoga pants*).